# Selecting a column in SQL

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I want to use the `ALTER table SET column1 = column2` from Python. So far so easy, except I want to use it in the `ALTER table SET column1 = %s` format. Again no problem, except my variable from Python is a column number, so what a really need as my `%s` is something like `column[n]`, as in `row[n]`.

None of the options I have considered have been very elegant.
I could rename the columns as numbers, and do an integer to string conversion. But then updating the database manually gets to be a problem remembering what those numbers refer to.
I could have a conversion table in Python. But then changing the database is a recipe for confusion, with the references getting shifted.
Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. I've never seen ALTER table SET columnA = columnB before. What does it do? And where is the python script getting the column number from?

Comment: I've tagged it now as mysql. It works on the command line in SQL, after taking off safe mode (that took me longer to find than it should have done) The data contents of columnB are copied to columnA

Comment: 'ALTER TABLE changes the structure of a table.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html ALTER table SET is not a an option in mysql - if you want to copy the contents of one column to another use UPDATE. https://dbfiddle.uk/KQffz2as